# Unable to run systemctl commands on the host from the container which was working till Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, systemd, docker, cgroup

When the host OS is Ubuntu 16.04 or RHEL 7.x, the following command is working, helping us to run systemctl commands on the host from within the docker container:

```
# nsenter --mount=/hostroot/proc/1/ns/mnt -- systemctl start dummy.service
```

But in the newer host OS-es, Ubuntu 20.04 and RHEL 8.x, this doesn't work and we get the following error:

```
# nsenter --mount=/hostroot/proc/1/ns/mnt -- systemctl start dummy.service
Failed to connect to bus: No data available
```

I have attached a minimalistic example and commands to run and reproduce the issue:

Sample service which I wanted to start on the host, from the container:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/dummy.service
[Unit]
Description=dummy service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sleep infinity
```

Dockerfile of my container:

```
# cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV TZ=UTC
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt update -y --fix-missing
RUN apt install -y util-linux
STOPSIGNAL SIGRTMIN+3
CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]
```

Build the image:

```
# docker build -t trial .
```

Delete any stale containers:

```
# docker rm -f trial
```

Run the image:

```
# docker run -it -d --net=host --privileged -v /:/hostroot -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --name trial trial
```

Reproduce the issue:

```
# docker exec -it trial bash
# nsenter --mount=/hostroot/proc/1/ns/mnt -- systemctl start dummy.service
Failed to connect to bus: No data available
```

I would like to know if there are any additional options or any docker run command that needs to be altered to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into this for a good several hours, it seems the method [sd_bus_start](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/be7148ebed5d73c4a76bc6089ebe2e82d8fa33e0/src/libsystemd/sd-bus/sd-bus.c#L1188) was changed to include additional checks. I wasn't able to narrow down what else it is looking for, however I was able to come up with a more elegant solution to accomplish the same task using remote systemctl commands instead of mounting all the directories from the host.

## Remote systemctl

`systemctl` supports remote commands via the `--host / -H` flag. It is using ssh to connect to the remote host, so an ssh key pair will be needed. Since we are controlling the host we are on, this is pretty straightforward to setup.

### Docker command (or Kubernetes arg)

Here is the full command that can be used, I will break down each part below. The assumptions of the container are that it has `systemctl` and `ssh` installed, the container is running on the host network, and that the `root` account's home directory is mounted (you can use another use if you want).

```bsh
(ls ~/.ssh/id_rsa || ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N "") 
  && (grep -qxF $(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) ~/.ssh/authorized_keys || echo $(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys)
  && (grep -qxF "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ~/.ssh/config || echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config)
  && (grep -qxF "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" ~/.ssh/config || echo "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" >> ~/.ssh/config)
  && systemctl -H root@127.0.0.1 start nfs-server.service
```

This command is seeing if the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file exists, otherwise create one.

```bsh
(ls ~/.ssh/id_rsa || ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N "")
```

Now we add our public key to our authorized keys if it does not exist in the file already.

```bsh
(grep -qxF "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" ~/.ssh/authorized_keys || echo "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys)
```

This can probably be made more secure by putting it in a section of the ssh config only for `127.0.0.1`, but we need

```bsh
(grep -qxF "StrictHostKeyChecking no" ~/.ssh/config || echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config) 
  && (grep -qxF "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" ~/.ssh/config || echo "UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null" >> ~/.ssh/config)
```

Finally we have the actual `systemctl` command. Notice the `-H root@127.0.0.1`.

```bsh
systemctl -H root@127.0.0.1 start nfs-server.service
```

For maximum security, it would be best to setup the keys and users outside of the containers first (via Ansible or similar) and only allow the `systemctl -H` command inside the container.

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time on this. We also internally arrived at a very similar inference (though via observation-only & not code reading) that some additional new checks are causing the change in behavior.

We also noted that in earlier OS-es, such command execution resulted in a crash. Likely systemd-dev fixed this issue which is causing behavioral anomalies to the end-user. 

The suggested solution by you is the same one we got recommended from canonical as well.

Thanks